# Задать допустимый интервал данных в моделях sklearn

Tags: python, sklearn

Необходмо построить прогноз данных, которые могут принамать значения из диапазона (например, количество чего-то >=0 или доля ~ [0;1]). Прогнозирую регерссией из `sklearn` и иногда модель дает недопустимый прогноз. Есть ли в `sklearn` реализованное решение?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню по `Data Science` соревнованиям, обычно в этих случаях просто обрезают результат предсказания до нужного диапазона. Для этого можно использовать например функцию [numpy.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).

Есть ещё такая штука как [калибровка вероятности](https://scikit-learn.ru/1-16-probability-calibration/), но это уже про изменение формы распределения вероятностей предсказания внутри диапазона.

А сильное ли у вас выпадение из диапазона? Если не сильное, то достаточно "подрезать" результат. А если сильное, то в этом случае нужно разбираться в чём дело. Возможно, будет эффективнее найти выбросы и убрать их из выборки перед обучением. Либо наоборот выбросы есть в тестовой выборке и нужно что-то с ними делать (приводить к диапазону? заменять на среднее?). В общем, в этом случае нужно разбираться с данными, а не "лечить симптомы".